# Black screen on laptop after Windows restart

Tags: windows, laptop, display

I have problems with Lenovo G700 laptop. Recently I've replaced it's LCD screen, the original one got broken. Everything worked ok for about 2 weeks until I've installed some Windows 10 updates. After restart, screen went black, nothing could be seen. Screen was illuminated, but there was no picture at all. First I thought there is a software problem but when I connected laptop with external monitor, picture was shown (windows loaded normally). I even formatted the whole hard drive and obviously windows were not the problem here. One more thing I've noticed - even when I've got external monitor plugged in, Lenovo logo was NOT shown, I couldn't even get to BIOS - picture appeared when windows loading started.

It looks like there's some hardware problem, but I'm running out of ideas what to check next. On the other hand it seems quite a coincidence that hardware failure appeared just after I've installed windows updates. Screen guarantee hasn't expired yet, but I'd like to be sure that screen is defected. Is there something else to check first?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: If you feel able to, update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers (use the External Monitor).  Restart, see if the laptop display is working and if not, explore the warranty return.

Comment: @John Well, I've formatted hard drive but I can't even get to BIOS even if I use external monitor. No picture is shown, I've tried to install Windows 10 again (using USB) but no luck. With Windows USB plugged in, no picture appears so there's not much I can do now.

Comment: The screen appears to have a hardware issue. You can check all the connections but they should not go bad or loosen in two weeks, so it appears to be an early screen failure.

Comment: @John It all seems like that, yes. I've already checked all the connections, so I guess I'll have to replace the screen again.

Answer (score 0):

> After restart, screen went black, nothing could be seen. Screen was
> illuminated, but there was no picture at all. ...  It looks like
> there's some hardware problem.

Background:  You checked drivers and connections and the screen stays dark.

At this point it is an early screen failure and needs to be replaced again.